# How do I get a string right before a certain character in SSIS 2008?

Tags: sql, ssis

I've been seeing a lot of answers online but none of them give me exactly what I need.

Example:

12345_helloworld_328923_haha.txt

I need to grab everything before the SECOND "_"

output:

helloworld

How do I do this as an expression in SSIS?

Comment: What have you tried? Is this on a column or a variable? whats the column / variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName],"_",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName],"_",2) - FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName],"_",1) - 1)
```